# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sagemaker'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, amazon-sagemaker

I am attempting to perform pre-processing using sklearn in sagemaker. As a pre-requisite I am trying to import sagemaker module:

```
%pip install -qU 'sagemaker>=2.15.0'
import boto3
import sagemaker
```

but I get error as:

```
An error was encountered:
No module named 'sagemaker'
Traceback (most recent call last):
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sagemaker'
```

Any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This error message means that, despite your first line of code, the sagemaker module was not installed on your system. Remove the `-q` (quiet) option to see the error message and why the module wasn't installed. My guess is that you need to use double quotes instead of single quotes when specifying a specific version number (e.g. `pip install "sagemaker>=2.15.0"`).

Comment: thanks, I figured i was trying to run this code in a spark notebook. the code worked as is in python3 notebook in sagemaker.